# How to fetch every sponsoredContent Linkedin UGC API

Tags: linkedin-api

I need to fetch every sponsored content share from a specific LinkedIn organization.

I'm using the `/adDirectSponsoredContents` endpoint to request this data but there are some shares that I can't reach in any way. Is this endpoint restricted to some type of post?

Is there any other endpoint to retrieve these shares?

PS: I do have all the permissions and data needed to make the requests.

Comment: Any help from the [analytics api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/getting-started)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the respective page has a lot of dark posts and the request doesn't return an ordered data and not even offer a way to order it.

To get the post I was looking I needed to get around 10k posts and retrieve each one in shares API to find its details. My application looks just the first hundred posts and that's why I was unable to find some posts.